# Lock failure in NDK RenderScript

Tags: android-ndk, renderscript

I copied `mono.rs` from the HelloComputeNDK sample and tried to use it in my
my own project. I got the following error:

```
E/bcc     (26797): Unable to acquire the read lock for /data/data/com.example.android.rs.hellocomputendk/app/mono.o! (Permission denied)
E/bcc     (26797): Failed to remove file: /data/data/com.example.android.rs.hellocomputendk/app/mono.o.lock - Unknown error -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change the `#pragma rs java_package_name(...` to my own app's package name.